# Proftpd setup on Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, ftp

I am a novice with Linux, I am trying to install a LAMP server for local testing, no external (public) access will be available to this server.

I have everything setup, what I would like to accomplish is when a specific user logs into the ftp, he should end up in the var/www/html directory by default with enough permissions to upload/change/delete anything in that folder.

I have the user setup, proftpd installed. How can I set up the proftpd.conf file to do this? And what permissions do I need to set on the apache home directory so I can make changes? I have no concern of security, this is for my internal network use only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examine the `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` file and set the `DefaultRoot` directive

```
DefaultRoot  /var/www/html
```

this will chroot you user to the /var/www/html tree.

Add the user to the group that owns the files in /var/www/html e.g. apache

`usermod -a -G apache user`

Then add write permission for group in /var/www/html

```
chmod -R g+w /var/www/html
```

Comment: I now get the following:
Command: MLSD
Response: 550 /: Permission denied
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: I turned off SE Linux and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks